# How many cubic inches of lead are in a one-pond sample of lead?

Tags: cubics

The average weight for cast lead is 708 pounds per cubic foot. Consider a one-pound sample of cast lead. How many cubic inches of lead are in the sample? Choose the closest answer. One cubic foot is the same as 12^3 cubic inches.

Comment: $708$ pounds occupy $12^3$ cubic inches. So $1$ pound occupies how many cubic inches?

Comment: The closest answer to what?